# Get Windows internet the settings when automatic is ticked

Tags: windows, proxy, internet-options

If I have *Automatically detect settings* then this tells Windows to go off and iscover what the settings should be (I think?).

How can I either get the address Windows is using to get the config. file or get the actual settings it's using?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384122(v=vs.85).aspx?

Comment: @CodeCaster Good link, thanks.  I can work with that.